# Is there a way to Download all notes/attachments from a Salesforce Opportunity?

Tags: attachment, data-export

I have found it time comsuming to click into each note/attachement and click save to a certain folder.  Is there a tool that would allow me to pull all attachments from an opportunity to a folder on my desktop?

Comment: Datasert Realforce does this with ease, including determining appropriate file name extension based on content type, archiving files and creating folder structure for documents (disclaimer: I'm part of the product team)

Answer (score 4):

One simple app is there on salesforce called "**[Mass file Download](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcsAOUAZ)**". This app Download Multiple Files on a single click. It supports Mass download of Attachments, Files, Static Resource and Documents as a zip throughout the organization on record level.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcsAOUAZ

Comment: App Link: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcsAOUAZ

Answer (score 2):

You can export all notes and attachments using open-source sfdx-hardis plugin command

- First, define a files export

`sfdx hardis:org:configure:files`

- Then, run the files export

`sfdx hardis:org:files:export`

More details in this [article](https://nicolas.vuillamy.fr/how-to-mass-download-notes-and-attachments-files-from-a-salesforce-org-83a028824afd)

[image]

*Disclaimer: My company authors sfdx-hardis plugin*

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool  which can download all Salesforce document/attachmets. But not sure if it can be narrowed down to single records.

Tool name is "[FileExporter](http://www.opfocus.com/blog/fileexporter-a-nifty-tool-for-mass-exporting-salesforce-files/)". It allows to download Salesforce files into specific folder correctly by command-line.

Also you can always download files in ZIP format from `Setup > Data Management > Data Export` a built-in functionality from Salesfroce.

Alternatively, If you need some automation then you can create custom webservice and a small desktop application. But keep remember 6MB G-limit.

You cannot achieve this by Visualforce or Apex code there is a heap-size G-limit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea out of left field. The app Drawloop is fantastic for dealing with attachments. You could create a button on your Opportunity record, use some Javascript to query the IDs of the attachments and use Drawloop's FTP option to save them to an FTP location. http://support.drawloop.com/lds/ddp-help/deliveries/attach/

Yeah, it's a bit out there and it does cost, but the app is fantastic for mail merging and emails anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The App mentioned elsewhere in this thread is paid and USD 120/year per user.

But here is another one that's free and has a few other features like a flow component you can include for file downloading.

[Salesforce: Mass File Downloader](https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2022/01/11/salesforce-mass-file-downloader/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the collection of tools to mass download/upload files: [XL-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler/)

Answer (score -1):

There is - the tool name is SFDC Developer ;)

There is no standard way to do that, but I think it shouldn't be hard for you to develop some VF Page or simple JavaScript button to do this job.

Answer (score -1):

Use Jitterbit Harmony,

1) Create a new Target in: Targets->Files and name it AttachmentFile

2) Browse for a folder and set a File name

3) Create a new Query and query Attachements

4) In the mapping edit the code for the Body Mapping to:

```
<trans>
$fn = root$transaction.response$body$queryResponse$result$records.Attachment$Name$;
WriteFile("<TAG>Targets/Files/AttachmentFile</TAG>",Base64Decode(root$transaction.response$body$queryResponse$result$records.Attachment$Body$),$fn);
FlushFile("<TAG>Targets/Files/AttachmentFile</TAG>");
</trans>
```

Run the query and the attachements will go to the folder.

Answer (score -1):

Here iscommand line tool I wrote, which helps extract documents/attachments/contenversion selectively:

http://www.sfdctimes.com/export_sfdc_files/

Comment: currently is a broken link

Answer (score -2):

You can  download files in ZIP format from Setup > Data Management > Data Export

Comment: That downloads all the data from the org. The question is about downloading attachments from a single opportunity.

Answer (score -3):

file exporter is giving some error so I have written some apex code to move all required documents into some x record "attachment" and from there I have downloaded all by using dataloader.io

```
public class uppicsExtract{
    public void upppicsExtract(){  
        // here I have some code to file "upimages" set and after below is the code 
        for(Document  d: [SELECT Body,Id,Name,Type,contentType  FROM Document where id=:upimages]){
            Attachment a=new Attachment();
            a.body=d.body;
            a.name=d.name;
            a.contentType =d.contentType;
            a.ParentId='a3Vn00000008vMk';
            attachList.add(a);
        }  
        insert attachList;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to export, this will insert new records.